# how can i modify my HTML code

Tags: html, css

i want to modify my HTML code like a Toggle Switch and when i turn Toggle Switch OFF it will send /relay1off and then Toggle Switch ON it will send /relay1on

for example code:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6-d8uCmJ980cHdOWGpHZ1dSbHc/view?usp=sharing
    my code:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6-d8uCmJ980ci02c2g4clJQck0/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Please, do not post links to your code. Instead copy/paste the relevent code directly in the question.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)